# Is it true that $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x\in \mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ , $g$ be continuous from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ and suppose $f(r)=g(r)$ for all rational numbers $r$. Is it true that $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x\in \mathbb R$

I am really struggling on how to prove this question here.any hint .i do not know where to start from with this one?

Comment: Hint: Any real number is a limit of rational numbers.

Comment: *Hint.* $\Bbb{Q}$ is dense in $\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: Expanding on the hint of @NicolasBourbaki, if $f$ is continuous then for any sequence $x_n\to x$ it follows that $\lim f(x_n) = f(\lim x_n) = f(x)$...

Comment: Perhaps write down your definition of "continuous", then see if you can use that to prove this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** epsilon-delta definition of continuity and proof by contradiction.

$$$$

$$$$

$$$$

**Solution:** Suppose $f(x_0)\neq g(x_0)$ for some $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$. Then, $|f(x_0)-g(x_0)|>0$ and thus we can take $\varepsilon=|f(x_0)-g(x_0)|/2$ in the definition of continuity.

Since $f$ is continuous, there exists $\delta_1>0$ such that

$$x\in (x_0-\delta_1,x_0+\delta_1)\quad\Rightarrow\quad |f(x)-f(x_0)|<\frac{|f(x_0)-g(x_0)|}{2}\tag{1}$$

Since $g$ is continuous, there exists $\delta_2>0$ such that
$$x\in (x_0-\delta_2,x_0+\delta_2)\quad \Rightarrow \quad |g(x)-g(x_0)|<\frac{|f(x_0)-g(x_0)|}{2}\tag{2}$$

Take a rational number $r\in(x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)$, where $\delta=\min\{\delta_1,\delta_2\}$. It follows from $(1)$ and $(2)$ that

$$
\begin{align}|f(x_0)-g(x_0)|&\leq |f(x_0)-f(r)|+|f(r)-g(r)|+|g(r)-g(x_0)|\\
&<\frac{|f(x_0)-g(x_0)|}{2}+0+\frac{|f(x_0)-g(x_0)|}{2}\\
&=|f(x_0)-g(x_0)|,
\end{align}$$
which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Hint 3: The function $f(x)-g(x) ==0$ in $\mathbb Q$. Now use density of $\mathbb Q$, then use sequential continuity: for every Real $y$ , since $ \mathbb Q$ is dense in the Reals, there is a sequence {$y_n$} with $y_n \rightarrow y$. Now by sequential continuity, $(y_n \rightarrow y) \rightarrow .....$.

Comment: Why considering $f-g$? This is not necessary and makes the proof only longer.

Comment: It is a 2.5-line proof, how much shorter do you want it?

Comment: Consider $f$ and $g$ (not $f-g$), then it just one line.

Comment: Don't you think redundancy may be good for an intro level? I could make my own argument shorter by skipping some points. But maybe it is good to see something longer to digest it better. Category theory will come soon after and it will just be a bunch of arrows. Enjoy the sloppiness for a bit.

Comment: No. $\phantom{---}$

Comment: Then maybe you can write your separate proof. I think it helps as part of my teaching philosophy, with which you can freely disagree. Let's also wait to see how the Op feels about it after all, isn't that what matters most?

Comment: The comment by TravisJ is (almost) the whole proof.

Answer (score 0):

We shall prove that “If $f:R \to R$ be continuous, and $f(x) = 0~\forall~x\in Q$, then $f(x) = 0 ~\forall ~x \in R$.”

***Proof***: Let $p\in R-Q$ such that $f(p)=k\neq 0$. Consider $\epsilon = |k|$. Now, $f$ is continuous on R $\implies$ $\exists ~\delta>0$ such that $\forall ~x\in (p-\delta, p+\delta)$, $|f(x)-f(p)| < |k|$ $\implies |f(x)-k|<|k|$ $\implies$
either, $2k<f(x)<0$ (if $k<0$) or $0<f(x)<2k$ (if $k>0$). In both the cases $f(x) \neq 0$ $\forall~x\in (p-\delta, p+\delta)$, which is a contradiction since for any rational $\alpha \in (p-\delta, p+\delta)$,$~f(\alpha)=0$.

**Note**: For your problem just take $\phi(x) = f(x)-g(x)$ and apply our proved result on $\phi$.

Comment: There are already answers, and yours doesn't add anything new.